# iterate mysql table in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an array containning some mysql tables and I want to iterate and visualize.
For example but the programm is not working

```
  tab=["spectreH20","spectreH50"]   
  for features in tab:
  sqlf="select * from WHERE table_name like",features                           
  df=sql.read_sql(sqlf,conn)
  print df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

`"select * from WHERE table_name like"` isn't a valid SQL query, and `sqlf = "select * from WHERE table_name like", features` isn't a valid string formatting, so `sqlf` ends up being a tuple.

In an ideal world you would use a parameterized query (or "prepared statement"), but these don't work for the FROM clause.

As a compromise, you can simply use string formatting:

```
 tab=["spectreH20", "spectreH50"]   
 for features in tab:
     sqlf = "select * from {}".format(features)                         
     df = sql.read_sql(sqlf,conn)
     print df
```

But be aware that this method is exposed to SQL injection and shouldn't be used in general (depends if you trust the source from which `features` is inputted).

Your best option is to simply hardcode the queries.